# FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory

Tags: python, pygame, file-not-found, image-loading

I'm new to programming and just following the steps provided online to build an easy game by python. I'm using VSC.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

# size screen
screen_width = 480
screen_height = 640
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

# title 
pygame.display.set_caption("Practice")

#load strite
character = pygame.image.load(('character.png'))
character_size = character.get_rect().size
character_width = character_size[0]
character_height = character_size[1]
character_x_pos = screen_width / 2 - character_width
character_y_pos = screen_height - character_height

# event loop
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            running = False
    screen.fill((117,217,242))
    screen.blit(character, (character_x_pos, character_y_pos))
    pygame.display.update()

# end game
pygame.quit()
```

And I got the output:

```
pygame 2.0.0.dev10 (SDL 2.0.12, python 3.8.3)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/suyeon/Documents/pythonWorkspace/pygame_basic/3_main_strite.py", line 15, in <module>
    character = pygame.image.load(('character.png'))
FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory.
```

I've tried character =

```
pygame.image.load(('C:/Users/suyeon/Documents/pythonWorkspace/pygame_basic/character.png'))

pygame.image.load(("C:/Users/suyeon/Documents/pythonWorkspace/pygame_basic/character.png"))

pygame.image.load(('C:\\Users\\suyeon\\Documents\\pythonWorkspace\\pygame_basic\\character.png'))
```

But all of them made the same error.

character.png is in the same folder.

Comment: How about `pygame.image.load('character.png')` which removes the extra parentheses? [pygame.image.load()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load) for reference.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh It's not working and saying the same error message  

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the path, from the [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html) I don't think you should pass the path in double brackets.

`pygame.image.load(r'C:/Users/suyeon/Documents/pythonWorkspace/pygame_basic/character.png')`

I would check that you can access the file using the `os` module, you can also pass a file object, instead of a path as well as well.

Comment: It doesn't work.. I've tried #import os   pygame.image.load(os.path.join('C:/','Users','suyeon','Documents','pythonWorkspace','pygame_basic', 'character.png')) as well

Comment: can you verify that the path exists using os.path.exists(path), or os.path.isfile(path)

Comment: `import os

a = os.path.lexists("/Users/suyeon/Documents/pythonWorkspace/pygame_basic/character.png")

print(a) `              It printed True

Comment: in that case, you could try ....load(os.path.abspath("/Users/suyeon/Documents/pythonWorkspace/pygame_basic/character.png"))

Comment: its not an elegant solution - I would look to check what the return value of os.path.abspath("/Users/suyeon/Documents/pythonWorkspace/pygame_basic/character.png") is, maybe investigate what your current paths and working directories are

Answer (score 1):

I think your terminal is not working on the same directory.
Make your python directory and terminal directory same

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try using 
`pygame.image.load((r'C:/Users/suyeon/Documents/pythonWorkspace/pygame_basic/character.png'))`

while specifying the path.

Comment: Just tried it but it doesn't work. The error message says the same thing.